# Dplyr write a function with column names as inputs

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm writing a function that I'm going to use on multiple columns in dplyr, but I'm having trouble passing column names as inputs to functions for dplyr.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
df<-tbl_df(data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B"), each=3), var1=sample(1:100, 6), var2=sample(1:100, 6)))


example<-function(colname){
  df %>%
    group_by(group)%>%
    summarize(output=mean(sqrt(colname)))%>%
    select(output)
}
example("var1")
```

Output should look like

```
df %>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  summarize(output=mean(sqrt(var1)))%>%
  select(output)
```

I've found a few similar questions, but nothing that I could directly apply to my problem, so any help is appreciated. I've tried some solutions involving eval, but I honestly don't know what exactly I'm supposed to be passing to eval.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré no, because there's no object named var1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you expected?

```
df<-tbl_df(data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B"), each=3), var1=sample(1:100, 6), var2=sample(1:100, 6)))

example<-function(colname){
  df %>%
    group_by(group)%>%
    summarize(output=mean(sqrt(colname)))%>%
    select(output)
}
example( quote(var1) )
#-----
Source: local data frame [2 x 1]

    output
1 7.185935
2 8.090866
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thanks, I was worried the answer was going to be much more complicated

Comment: I'm not a big dplyr user and so I'm wondering why the function `select` is needed. (Taking it out doesn't seem to affect behavior in the small (n=1) number of tests I've done.)

Comment: @BondedDust it's not needed. The use of `summarize()` collapse the result to `output`. You can safely remove it.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not work anymore in R 3.6 / dplyr 0.8.

As suggested [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641058/9285732), one can use `!!as.name()`

This works for me:

```
df<-tbl_df(data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B"), each=3), var1=sample(1:100, 6), var2=sample(1:100, 6)))

example<-function(colname){
  df %>%
    group_by(group)%>%
    summarize(output=mean(sqrt(!!as.name(colname)))%>%
    select(output)
}
example( quote(var1) )
```

If one additionally wants to have the column names to assign to in a `mutate`, then the easiest is to use the assignment `:=`. For example to replace *colname* with its square root.

```
example_mutate<-function(colname){
  df %>%
    mutate(!!colname := sqrt(!!as.name(colname)))
}
example_mutate( quote(var1) )
```

`quote()` can of course be replaced with quotation marks `""`.