# Using column names as function arguments

Tags: r, dplyr

With a data frame,  I'm using dplyr to aggregate some column like below.

```
> data <- data.frame(a=rep(1:2,3), b=c(6:11))
> data
  a  b
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 1  8
4 2  9
5 1 10
6 2 11
> data %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(tot=sum(b))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a   tot
  <int> <int>
1     1    24
2     2    27
```

This is perfect. However I want to create a re-usable function for this such that a column name can be passed as argument.

Looking at answers to related questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042577/3206440), I tried the following.

```
sumByColumn <- function(df, colName) {
  df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarize(tot=sum(colName))
  df
}
```

However I'm not able to get it working.

```
> sumByColumn(data, "b")

 Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument. 

> sumByColumn(data, b)

 Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'b' not found. 
>
```

Comment: You should consult [this blog post about programming with __`dplyr`__](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This can work using the latest `dplyr` syntax (as can be seen on [github](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/issues/116)):

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
sumByColumn <- function(df, colName) {
  df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarize(tot = sum(!! sym(colName)))
}

sumByColumn(data, "b")
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#      a   tot
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    24
#2     2    27
```

And an alternative way of specifying `b` as a variable:

```
library(dplyr)
sumByColumn <- function(df, colName) {
  myenc <- enquo(colName)
  df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarize(tot = sum(!!myenc))
}

sumByColumn(data, b)
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#      a   tot
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    24
#2     2    27
```

Comment: this works ... However if I were to add `filter( !!myenc > 7 ) ` before `group_by` it doesn't return any rows. What would be the right way to specify the column name inside `filter()` ?

Comment: This is part of the documentation. Instead of `!!` (which is a convenience function and which is not working with logical vectors), use `UQ` which is the proper function. i.e. `filter(UQ(myenc) > 7)`. Then it works fine.

Answer (score 14):

We can use `{{}}`:

```
library(dplyr)

sumByColumn <- function(df, colName) {
  df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarize(tot=sum({{colName}}))
}

sumByColumn(data, b)

#      a   tot
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    24
#2     2    27
```

Answer (score 6):

`dplyr` now also provides helper functions (`summarise_at`, which accepts arguments `vars`, `funs`) for this

```
sumByColumn <- function(df, colName) {
  df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(colName), funs(tot = sum))
}
```

provides the same answer

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      # a   tot
  # <int> <int>
# 1     1    24
# 2     2    27
```

Comment: Note that the last line could be: `summarize_at(colName, sum)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, `funs(tot = sum)` in case OP wanted to rename the column

Comment: verbs with _at are now depleted, so the other answers are preferable for people who get to this question nowadays.

Answer (score 6):

We can use the `.data` pronoun.

```
library(dplyr)

sumByColumn <- function(df, colName) {
  df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarise(tot = sum(.data[[colName]]))
}

sumByColumn(data, "b")

#      a   tot
#* <int> <int>
#1     1    24
#2     2    27
```